# Why android.telephony.SmsManager is not able to send message from Dialog Activity?

Tags: android

Here I have created an alert DialogActivity where "setPositiveButton" builder, launch a simple dialog and try to send an android telephony sms message to the recipient.

But mysteriously the dialog is not able to send sms to the recipient. Would you please help me to understand the reason ?

Here is the code :

```
package com.example.demo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DialogActivity extends Activity 
{   
    private Dialog mDialog;
    String editTextEnterMobileNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder
        .setTitle("Incoming Server Message")
        .setMessage("text")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("eReceipt?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();

                mDialog = new Dialog(DialogActivity.this);
                mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.ereceipt_dialog);                       
                mDialog.setTitle("User Input");
                editTextEnterMobileNum = ((EditText) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.eReceiptEditText)).getText().toString();
                mDialog.findViewById(R.id.eReceiptOkButton).setOnClickListener(
                        new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dismissDialog();
                                try{
                                    android.telephony.SmsManager mSmsManager = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
                    mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(editTextEnterMobileNum, null, SmsReceiver.msgContent, null, null);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your SMS has sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                                   catch(Exception e){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your SMS sent has failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                   }                        

                            }
                        });

                mDialog.show();              
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        //finish();
    }

    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    }

}
```

And The Logcat output is :

```
03-13 18:09:58.139: E/ViewRootImpl(21086): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-13 18:10:13.999: W/System.err(21086): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:120)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at com.watchdata.qposdemo.DialogActivity$1$1.onClick(DialogActivity.java:66)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
03-13 18:10:14.009: W/System.err(21086):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 18:10:14.629: E/ViewRootImpl(21086): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-13 18:10:14.724: D/AbsListView(21086): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
03-13 18:10:14.724: D/AbsListView(21086): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-13 18:10:14.729: D/AbsListView(21086): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-13 18:10:14.744: D/AbsListView(21086): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
03-13 18:10:14.744: D/AbsListView(21086): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-13 18:10:14.749: D/AbsListView(21086): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
03-13 18:10:14.749: D/AbsListView(21086): unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-13 18:10:14.854: D/AbsListView(21086): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

During debugging, execution fails to enter into OnClickListener() of the

```
mDialog.findViewById(R.id.eReceiptOkButton).setOnClickListener(
                        new OnClickListener() {
```

I am not able to figure out why ?

Comment: Can you post the exception? Logcat?

Comment: @Boban S : I have re-edited with exception statement captured by logcat.

Comment: The logcat you posted is no related to the code for sending SMS. Do you event have errors in logcat?

Comment: The error shows the reason `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress`, you have entered invalid number

Comment: Thanks Boban for pointing out the issue... I analyzed and resolved the issue and have reposted the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers! Problem got resolved.

There were no appropriate intantiation of the phone number field of the mSmsManager.sendTextMessage() method. Alas! how silly mistake i made which took some time to figure out. I believe i got mislead because of nesting of onClickListener() methods. He he...

I am reposting the correct code to let be helpful for others.

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity 
{   
    private Dialog mDialog;
    String editTextEnterMobileNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder
        .setTitle("Incoming Server Message")
        .setMessage("text")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("eReceipt?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();

                mDialog = new Dialog(DialogActivity.this);
                mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.ereceipt_dialog);                       
                mDialog.setTitle("User Input");
                final EditText phoneNo = (EditText) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.eReceiptEditText);
                mDialog.findViewById(R.id.eReceiptOkButton).setOnClickListener(
                        new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dismissDialog();
                                String number = phoneNo.getText().toString();
                                try{
                                    android.telephony.SmsManager mSmsManager = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
                    mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, SmsReceiver.msgContent, null, null);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your SMS has sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                                   catch(Exception e){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your SMS sent has failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                   }                        

                            }
                        });

                mDialog.show();              
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        //finish();
    }

    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the text from the number field.

Replace the row

```
mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(editTextEnterMobileNum, null, SmsReceiver.msgContent, null, null);
```

with this one

```
mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(editTextEnterMobileNum.getText().toString(), null, SmsReceiver.msgContent, null, null);
```

Comment: S : But i have done the same as you asked before used in mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(). Yah the real problem lies with no appropriate instantiate of "editTextEnterMobileNum". Thank you for pointing out the problem.  I would edit with the correct code to help others.