# Why does app crash on start only on api 26

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app working on every api completely but in android 8 api 26 it crashes and I don't know why this happend .

The app use sms sending and receiving permissions and I put all requestPermissions in activity and manifests. Target sdk is on 26

Here the logcat of android studio error when app crash:

```
hapital.com.BitCar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: hapital.com.BitCar, PID: 25271
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hapital.com.BitCar/hapital.com.BitCar.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:320)
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:312)
    at hapital.com.BitCar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:194)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Invalid destinationAddress ?? what does it mean??

For example it has an error on `SmsManager.java` when open it just like pic  below has error in import libraries
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIIVK.png)

Could someone help what should i do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031643/why-android-telephony-smsmanager-is-not-able-to-send-message-from-dialog-activit

Comment: may the destination address is wrong while you sending a text message. so please post your code of oncreate method and sending a text message method

Comment: i dont use sms reading or sending method in oncreate but it just crash on start app

here is my method to send sms :


 SharedPreferences panelnumber = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String string_from_sp = panelnumber.getString("myStringName", "");

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(string_from_sp.toString(),
                    null,
                    smsBody.toString(),
                    null,
                    null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the problem

problem was in layout of activity that i used NavigationView like belo :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="230dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />
```

and in api 26 and higher not support

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of `SmsManager`, that exception is thrown when you call `sendTextMessage` with a destination address parameter that is `null` or an empty `String`.

If your code to send the SMS (as per your comment) is this:

```
 SharedPreferences panelnumber = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String string_from_sp = panelnumber.getString("myStringName", ""); 
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(string_from_sp.toString(), null,
                            smsBody.toString(), null, null);
```

then it follows that `string_from_sp` is a `null` or empty `String`.

Given the way you are initializing that variable, either:

- the `"mystringName"` field retrieved from the preferences is empty, or
- you have the preference field name incorrect, and you are getting the default value which you have specified to be an empty `String`.

---

There is not sufficient info to explain why this happens with API 26 only ... if that is what you are saying.